# WPF disable DataGrid Cell

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to disable [read only] a `DataGridCell` based on the program returned from database. I am using the following code but it's not working

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="SizeToCells" x:Name="amountColumn" Header="Amount"  Binding="{Binding Amount}"  MinWidth="100" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
         <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RoleName}" Value="Payment Authoriser" >
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DDA0DC" />
                     <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Please Add Amount" />
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
 <Setter Property="DedableThisCell" Value="Please DesableMe" />
```

`GridCell` will be only writable when `RoleName="Payment Maker"` ELSE anything for `RoleName`, It will be readonly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RoleName}" Value="Payment Maker" >
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Hi I want to Keep RoleName="Payment Maker" than True Else False

Comment: @user3624511 can you get away with disabling the entire `DataGrid`? Can you try `IsEnabled = false` on the `DataGrid` and see if the `Cell` is enabled by the `DataTrigger`?

Comment: I have done something like that 
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RoleName}" Value="User" >
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                            </DataTrigger>


                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RoleName}" Value="Release User" >
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
! Good Approach
                                            </DataTrigger>

Comment: @user3624511 I agree that it would be preferred to write the code as "if PaymentMaker, then enable, else disable" as it would treat the default action as "disable", not "enable". How are you setting your default IsEnabled? Depending on where it is located, the dependency property precedence may be preventing the trigger from running